# Mysql Left join not like is very slow

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to speed up my query. I have 2 tables and try to sort out already used pictures.
I have tested several different combinations, but the query is still very slow.

images - id, title

news - id, img, msg

```
SELECT a.* FROM (
    SELECT images.id FROM images WHERE images.id NOT IN (SELECT news.img FROM news)
) a LEFT JOIN news AS n ON n.msg LIKE CONCAT('%[img]',a.id,'%') WHERE n.id IS NULL
```

How to make this faster? Thank you for help.

Comment: You need to rewrite the query to (a) have the join use the tables directly so it can benefit from indexes (b) do not use a %x% wildcard if possible since that cannot use an index either. If you can't do any of these changes then rewriting the database to be more relationally friendly might help like e.g. make a column that you can store the exact term you need to locate.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll create one more column in the database.